# Ошибка умножения матриц

Tags: python, numpy, матрицы, умножение

Пытаюсь подобрать матрицу поворота для зануления a_ij элемента в матрице путем домножения на  ортогональную слева и справа, те (E.transpose() @ A @ E)[i][j] должно равняться нулю. В первом принте функции R я сначала высчитываю этот элемент руками, а во втором принте после умножение матриц средствами numpy, а ответы не сходятся. В чем дело?

```
import numpy as np

def R(A, i, j):  # возвращает матрицу поворота (i < j) зануляющую a_ij и a_ji
    E = np.eye(A.shape[0])
    fi = 0.0
    if (np.isclose(A[i][j], 0.0)):
        fi = 0.0
    else:
        fi = (np.pi / 2.0 - np.arctan((A[i][i] - A[j][j]) / (2.0 * A[i][j]))) / 2.0
    E[i][i] = np.cos(fi)
    E[j][j] = np.cos(fi)
    E[i][j] = (-1.0) * np.sin(fi)
    E[j][i] = np.sin(fi)
    print(np.cos(fi) * ((-1.0) * np.sin(fi) * A[i][i] + np.cos(fi) * A[i][j]) + np.sin(fi) * (
               (-1.0) * (np.sin(fi) * A[j][i]) + np.cos(fi) * A[j][j]))# печатает (E.transpose() @ A @ E)[i][j]
    print((E.transpose() @ A @ E)[i][j])
    return E


def create_random_symmetrical_matrix(n):
    A = np.eye(n)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i + 1):
            value = np.random.random() * 1000.0
            A[i][j] = value
            A[j][i] = value
    return A


A = create_random_symmetrical_matrix(2)
print(A)
R(A, 0, 1)
```

Вывод:

```
[[696.08723412 536.07062297]
 [536.07062297 486.81976636]]
3.552713678800501e-14
4.7180975394217664e-14
```

Comment: `а ответы не сходятся` так они оба - практически ноль